# Integrating $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2-\frac{1}{x^2}}}dx$ using two substitutions $z = x^2$ and $u = 2z-1$

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

An exercise asks to calculate $$\int_1^y\frac{1}{\sqrt{2-\frac{1}{x^2}}}dx$$

The solution manual states that with the two substitutions $z = x^2$ and then $u = 2z -1$ we get 
$$\int_1^y\frac{1}{\sqrt{2-\frac{1}{x^2}}}dx = \int_1^{y^2}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2z-1}}dz = \int_1^{2y^2-1}\frac{1}{4\sqrt{u}}du$$
I don't understand the first substitution. $\frac{dz}{dx} = 2x$, but I just don't get how the root in the denominator was transformed! Shouldn't $2x$ be a factor in the integrand for this substitution to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$z = x² \rightarrow dz = 2 x dx \rightarrow \frac{dz}{dx} = 2x$$
$$dx = \frac{dz}{2x} \rightarrow \int_1^y\frac{1}{\sqrt{2-\frac{1}{x^2}}}dx = \int_1^{y²}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2-\frac{1}{x^2}}} \frac{dz}{2x} = \int_1^{y²}\frac{1}{\sqrt{8x²-4}} dz = \int_1^{y²}\frac{1}{\sqrt{8z-4}} dz = \int_1^{y^2}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2z-1}}dz$$

The top boundary changes because you are in the $z$ world in which $z = x²$ so $y \rightarrow y²$.

Then with $u= 2z-1$ I assume you've understood.

Answer (score 2):

Since one of the bounds of the integral is $1$ and you can't go past $0$, you can assume $x>0$. The substitution $x=\sqrt{z}$ thus yields
$$
\sqrt{2-\dfrac{1}{x^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{2z-1}}{\sqrt{z}}
$$
and
$$
dx=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{z}}\,dz
$$
so the integral becomes
$$
\int_1^{y^2}\frac{\sqrt{z}}{\sqrt{2z-1}}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{z}}\,dz
=\int_1^{y^2}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2z-1}}\,dz
$$
as stated.